# How can i solve dart.exe has stopped working

Tags: flutter, windows, dart, command-line, windows-10

I installed flutter sdk and when i try to run any *flutter* command on my computer it starts for a little bit and it shows me a dialogue saying *dart.exe has stopped working * and to close the program.

I tried to reinstall the sdk and downgrading it too but it shows me the same prompt every time.